# Exporting Deployable features for a specific java version

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I have an eclipse/osgi plugin that I need to export as a deploy-able feature. My plugin works in Java 1.7, however when it goes to export through eclipse, I get errors saying that certain things are not supported in 1.6. How can I specify that the exporting needs to use java 1.7 (eclipse builds and uses everything else in 1.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@TheDog: I understand that you need Eclipse to run on Java 7 before your plugin can be installed. In OSGi parlance, this is the *execution environment*.

In a post 4.3 release of OSGi, you can use the Require-Capability header:

```
 Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(|(osgi.ee=J2SE)(osgi.ee=JavaSE))(version>=1.7))"
```

Each OSGi framework provides an 'osgi.ee' capability for the environments it supports, in your case 1.7.

Before the environment became a capability, there was a special manifest header that will ensure that you can only install your bundle on a Java 7 environment:

```
 Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

This header is still supported by all frameworks.